# Continuity of an integral with parameter-dependent domain of integration

Tags: integration, continuity, parametric, semicontinuous-functions

I have an integral of the form:
$$g(s)=\int_{D(s)}f(x)dx,$$
where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $s\in\mathbb{R}$, $D(s)$ is a parameter-dependant subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ is a "nice" function (i.e. $f\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$) and the integral converges for all $s$.

I want to understand if $g(s)$ is continuous, in particular in the case where $D(s)$ is a compact and convex set with non-zero measure for all $s$. All results I was able to find on the topic (e.g. https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Parameter-dependent_integral) consider a parameter-dependent integrand, with a constant domain of integration. I tried to transform the problem with:
$$\int_{D(s)}f(x)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\chi_{D(s)}(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}h(x,s)dx.$$
However, $h(x,s)$ is not continuous in $s$, meaning that I cannot apply any of the results I found.

If it can help, I am familiar with the concept of hemicontinuity of set-valued functions, which intuitively might be related to this issue (maybe hemicontinuity of $D(s)$ implies continuity of $g(s)$?).

Anybody knows any related results? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any other assumptions on the assignment $s\mapsto D(s)$, for instance that if $s\geq s'$ then $D(s)\subset D(s')$, or $f$ maybe that is positive etc. ?

Comment: I mean the assignment $s\mapsto D(s):= \{s\}$ satisfies your assumptions and makes $h(s)$ continuous. So I suppose you want $D(s)$ to have non-zero measure or some other assumptions to say something useful.

Comment: @sein The only other assumptions I have on $D(s)$ is that it's the intersection of a finite number of half-spaces; additionally, it has always at least an interior point (so yes, it has non-zero measure). All half-spaces depend on $s$ in a strange way, so I don't have any nice property like the one you describe unfortunately..

Comment: How do they depend on $s$?

Comment: @sein Basically I'm intersecting a $n$-dimensional hyperplane (which is dependent on $s$) with a $m$-dimensional (constant) hypercube, with $m>n$. If we consider a local frame of reference on the hyperplane, this intersection is indeed the intersection of $n$-dimensional half-planes. However, I don't really have an explicit representation of the hyperplane w.r.t. to $s$, I just know the intersection is always non-empty.